# Accessing element of a List. C#

Tags: c#, list, object

I have created a List of type Students. The following classes are the ones I use;

```
public class StudentDetails
   {
   public class Address
    {
        public int HouseNumber{ get; set; }
        public string LineOne{ get; set; }
        public string LineTwo{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public Address StudentAddress{ get; set; }
    }



    public List<Student> GetStudents()
    {
    private Address StudentOne = new Address{//details};
    private Address StudentTwo = new Address{//details};

    var students = new List<Student>();
    students.add(new Student {StudentId = 1, StudentAdress = StudentOne, //details});
    //more students
    return students;
    }

}
```

Now I would like to access certain details of a particular student from this object. Say I want to get the House number of a student. How can i do that? I attempted to create another list, then add the list returned from `GetStudents()`. However when i iterate through it , i only get references to objects.

```
//To access the List 

  StudentDetails student = new StudentDetails(); //create new instance
  for (int i = 0; i < student.GetStudents().Count; i++)
  {
            //Console.WriteLine(student[1].GetStudents());
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx) to select the student you are searching for and then access its properties:

```
var student = GetStudents().FirstOrDefault(student => student.StudentId /* your student id here */>);
if (student != null)
{
    var houseNumber = student.Address.HouseNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
StudentDetails student = new StudentDetails(); //create new instance
foreach (var s in student.GetStudents())
{
   var id = s.StudentId;//use any properties using . operator
   Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: As `Student` doesn't override `ToString()` this will simply print the name of the class. Not really a useful answer.

Comment: @slugster Of course, I assume op knows to read `s.BlahBlah` etc

Comment: It will print the **type name** of the class, not its properties.

Comment: You've changed your code but it's still wrong - you want `Console.WriteLine(id);`

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine(GetStudents()[0].HouseNumber.ToString());
```

(0 can be whatever number)

or (gets a list of students and their house numbers) :

```
var houseNumbers = GetStudents().Select((student) => 
    String.Format("Student: {0} - {1}", 
    student.StudentId, student.Address.HouseNumber));
foreach(var entry in houseNumbers) Console.WriteLine(entry);
```